# How do I save logs to database in asp.net core 3.1 mvc web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, database, asp.net-core

I have Middleware that I want to use to log which user approached which page and what response they got

```
public class RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var request = await FormatRequest(context.Request);
        var originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;

        using (var responseBody = new MemoryStream())
        {
            context.Response.Body = responseBody;
            await _next(context);
            var response = await FormatResponse(context.Response);
            //TODO: Save log to chosen datastore
            await responseBody.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);
        }
    }

    private async Task<string> FormatRequest(HttpRequest request)
    {
        var body = request.Body;
        request.EnableBuffering();
        var buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(request.ContentLength)];
        await request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        var bodyAsText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
        request.Body = body;
        return $"{request.Scheme} {request.Host}{request.Path} {request.QueryString} {bodyAsText}";

    }

    private async Task<string> FormatResponse(HttpResponse response)
    {
        response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return $"{response.StatusCode}";
    }
```

How do I save data like (UserId; Username; URL; TimeStamp; StatusCode) into my database?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you want to use Serialization. So you have to look at Newton.Json nuget package.

```
Log log= new Log
{
    Email = "james@example.com",
    Active = true,
    CreatedDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 20, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
    Roles = new List<string>
    {
        "User",
        "Admin"
    }
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(log, Formatting.Indented);
```

Save json into db as a column.That's it.

Comment: While this will work, it will eliminate the benefits of actually storing it to the database due to not being able to query on columns.